# Do we need the [poke] tag on Meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

I want to discuss the usage of the [poke](/questions/tagged/poke) tag on Meta, as I think it is unnecessary.

While looking through some older questions here on Meta I found this question:

[Accept Answer Thursday](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/accept-answer-thursday)

The question introduced the [poke](/questions/tagged/poke) tag. The user created this tag to explain his idea of "poking" a person by using the @<Username> syntax in a comment of one of their questions or answers. [Tag excerpt:](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/poke/info)

> Draw a persons attention in comments by using the @Name. Ideally in the commends [sic!] of their answer or question.

Do we really need this tag? I think it does not really add anything to the site. I have never seen people refer to using the @<Username> syntax in a comment by calling it "poking" and this is the only question with this tag. A search for [poke is:q](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=poke+is%3Aq) and [poking is:q](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=poking+is%3Aq) only shows this one question. When looking for [poking is:a](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=poking+is%3Aa) I only find other usages of the word, like "I just decided to poke my head out".

Is it common to call this "poking" on the StackExchange network and I overlooked it the whole time?

Comment: I have heard notifying someone called poking, not sure if it was here or somewhere else though.

Comment: Looking at main meta it seems to be an accepted term https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=poke I doubt we'll need it as most questions about poking should go to main meta as they are rarely going to be a worldbuilding specific issue.

Comment: @Bellerophon It's perfectly fine to ask questions on site-specific meta sites that aren't specific to the site in question. You might get *better answers sooner* by asking on [meta.se], but it isn't required to ask there (and some people might prefer not to, or at least test the waters on site-specific metas first; for example, because there's actually a working reputation system in place there).

Comment: I think most people call it "notifying" Meta.se uses the tags "comment-replies" and "notifications"

Comment: The tag is gone now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tag in question is used by a single question, posted nearly three years ago.

That question is voted +6/-9 for a net -3.

The tag appears to try to describe something that is rather strongly discouraged by the only answer on the only question bearing that tag.

That answer is voted +15/-0 for a net +15.

Not only that; that answer is also written by a Stack Exchange *employee*.

**I see no real reason for the tag to exist.**